# How do you make one of your menu items open a combo box? in javafx

Tags: javafx

Basically what i'm trying to do is for my menu 2 to open a combo box where i can configure the settings of a cannon ball or pyramid in a combo box. I'm just wondering how to add this combo box and how to get it to open when someone clicks on ether of those menu 2 items. Thank you so much for your help ! Sorry ! if i formatted this incorrectly its my first time posting.

public class StackCannon extends Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    
    primaryStage.setTitle("Stack Cannon Balls");

   
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
 

    
    Menu menu = new Menu("File");
    MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Serialize");
    MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("Deserialize");
    SeparatorMenuItem separator = new SeparatorMenuItem();
    MenuItem menuItem3 = new MenuItem("Save as XML");
    MenuItem menuItem4 = new MenuItem("Load from XML");
    SeparatorMenuItem separator2 = new SeparatorMenuItem();
    MenuItem menuItem5 = new MenuItem("Save as JSON");
    MenuItem menuItem6 = new MenuItem("Load from JSON");
    SeparatorMenuItem separator3 = new SeparatorMenuItem();
    MenuItem menuItem7 = new MenuItem("Save to Database");
    MenuItem menuItem8 = new MenuItem("Load from Database");
    SeparatorMenuItem separator4 = new SeparatorMenuItem();
    MenuItem menuItem9 = new MenuItem("Exit");
    
    
    
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem1);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem2);
    menu.getItems().add(separator);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem3);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem4);
    menu.getItems().add(separator2);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem5);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem6);
    menu.getItems().add(separator3);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem7);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem8);
    menu.getItems().add(separator4);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem9);

     
 

    
    Menu menu2 = new Menu("Setup");
    MenuItem menuItem10 = new MenuItem("Configure Pyramid");
    MenuItem menuItem11 = new MenuItem("Configure Cannon Balls");
    
    menu2.getItems().add(menuItem10);
    menu2.getItems().add(menuItem11);
    
    menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);
    menuBar.getMenus().add(menu2);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    VBox vBox = new VBox(menuBar);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Comment: don't see any combobox nor any action in the menuitems .. time to work work through a tutorial on how to use menu/items

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. They depend on the functionality, layout and style needed.

One way to achieve that would be:

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.getItems().setAll("Alt 1", "Alt 2", "Alt 3");

Label label = new Label("ComboBox menu", comboBox);
label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

CustomMenuItem menuItem = new CustomMenuItem(label);

Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
menu.getItems().add(menuItem);

MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);
```